# Ansible extract var from JSON

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using the URI module and I get a JSON response back. This is my playbook so far.

```
.. some playbook ..
   register: output

  - debug: msg="{{ output }}"

  - name: get job id
    set_fact:
      job_id: "{{ output.json.results }}"

  - debug: msg="{{ job_id }}"
```

Here’s the output of job_id from the debug above:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "approval_state": "pending_approval",
            "created_on": "2018-12-18T22:48:40Z",
            "description": "Provision from [tpl] to [test]",
            "href": "https://foo.ca/api/provision_requests/1000000000143",
            "id": "1000000000143",
            "message": "VM Provisioning - Request Created",
            "options": {
                "addr_mode": [
                    "dhcp",
                    "DHCP"
                ],
                "auto_approve": false,
                "cluster_filter": [
                    null,
                    null
                ],
                "cores_per_socket": [
                    2,
                    "2"
                ],
```

I want to extract the “id” in the 5th line of the JSON output above. Any ideas?
I tried `output.json.results.id` but that errors out with no object id found

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the JSON that has been produced, you actually have a list of dictionaries, albeit in this particular case, you have a list containing a single dictionary. So given the exact example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ job_id[0].id }}"
```

will extract the id field.

If you want to extract the id fields from every dictionary in the list (assuming multiple dictionaries are possible), you could instead do:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ job_id | map(attribute='id') | list }}"
```

which will produce a simple list containing the contents of the id field in each dictionary.